# Task implemented in SWC in Autosar classic architecture

Tags: c, autosar, automotive, runtime-environment

I am working in a Project with autosar 4.3.
I am refering to an old version of the project where I can find that in a SW_C it is created a Task and using some OS primitive on it!

is it safe or allowed in the autosar SW application component to define /configure task in this level? Tasks should not be defined in the level of the RTE?
example:

```
TASK (diagQueuedJob)
{  
    ...
    OSwaiteven();
    OSgetevent();
    ....
}
```

Thanks for explanation

Comment: No, it should not be defined inside of SWCs. In your SWCD ARXMLs, you should just have RunnableEntities and their triggering events (e.g. TimingEvent) defined. The OS and RTE are used to configure tasks, events and through Rte(Bsw)EventToTaskMappings the Runnables are mapped to the tasks. The RTE then generates the according task bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact reference, but this is not allowed.
A application software component shall only use the interfaces generated by the RTE.

However, if you have a Complex Device Driver, this is allowed.
However, good practice would be to minimize this, because else you could put your whole legacy application in a single Complex Device Driver and call it AUTOSAR compliant.